# How to dynamically change view in angularjs using ui-router

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-show

I have a named view called `myView` in which I have two div elements that I want to show conditionally using `ng-show` based on whether the value of `$scope.states['currentState']` is `'A'` or `'B'`. The value of `$scope.states['currentState']` is changed when an anchor tag is clicked which calls the `doStuff` function on the `myController` controller.

The issue I am having is when the anchor tag is clicked and the `doStuff` function is clicked, it shows on the console that the value of `$scope.states['currentState']` has been modified, but its not updating the `myView` named view accordingly.

Following is the code for `app.js`, `myView.html` and `index.html` files. The `index.html` file is being used as a `<div ui-view></div>` in an `index.ejs` file that I am rendering using Express with Node.js.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']).

    config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                views: {

                    '': { templateUrl: 'partials/index.html' },

                    'myView@home': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/myView.html',
                        controller: 'myController'
                    },

                    'myOtherView@home': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/myOtherView.html',
                        controller: 'myController'
                    }
                }

            });

    }])

app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope){

    var states = ['A', 'B'];
    $scope.states = states;
    $scope.states['currentState'] = states['currentState'] || 'A';

    $scope.doStuff = function(toState) {
        //doing stuff
        $scope.states['currentState'] = toState;
        console.log($scope.states['currentState']);
    };

} ]);
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="content-page">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div ui-view="myView"></div>
                        <div ui-view="myOtherView"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**myView.html**

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-show="states['currentState'] == 'A'">
        //displaying this div if the currentState is A
        <a ng-click="doStuff('B')">Do stuff and show B</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="states['currentState'] == 'B'">
        //displaying this div if the currentState is B
    </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody help me understand that why am not getting the `div` with `states['currentState'] == 'B'` shown, even when I see the value of `console.log($scope.states['currentState'])` changed from 'A' to 'B' when the `doStuff` function is called in `myController`?

Edit:
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R2SUDhVZh0VA6YKxhGbp?p=preview) is the demo of the issue I am facing.

Comment: try $scope.apply() at the end of your update functions

Comment: @c0d3junk13: Here http://plnkr.co/edit/R2SUDhVZh0VA6YKxhGbp?p=preview is the demo that shows the given issue in action.

Comment: @c0d3junk13: `$scope.$apply();` at the end of the `doStuff` throws the `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay So I was mistaken in my comment.
The real issue was that you used {{}} in your ng-show which is not needed as these expect to take angular expressions.Also I would make current state a property  of your scope as at the moment you are trying to make it a property of an array inside your scope.
Hope that helps! Below is the modified code for your view:

```
<div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <div ng-show="currentState === 'A'">
    <a ng-click="doStuff('B')">Do stuff and show B</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="currentState === 'B'">
    <a ng-click="doStuff('A')">Do stuff and show A</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1llQMQEdxIwu65MNoorx?p=preview

Comment: I got them `{{` and `}}` left there by mistake, must have forgotten to save the updated plunkr. It's still not working after removing the `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: did you change current state to be it's own property on the scope object, you can't assign $scope.states a property it's an array.

Comment: Many thanks for the plunker :). `states['currentState']` also worked.

Comment: No problem, it's cool that it did but for future reference assigning keys to an array is kind of like making a half hash map half array abomination :L